# Digitizing Menu unavailable in QGIS 2.18.15

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I installed the latest version of QGIS 2.18.15 and the Digitizing menu seems to have disappeared in the properties options of vector layers. I want to enable the 'Use Last Attribute" feature

[image: QGIS Layer Properties]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats **general** settings, not layer settings. Go to "Settings" from the menu, you should see "Digitizing" there.